# Derivative of the matrix of eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, symmetric-matrices

Given a real symmetric matrix $A$ with entries depending on $t$, the derivative $p$-th eigenvalue with respect to $t$ is given by

$$
\lambda_p' = v_p^T A'v_p
$$

where $A'$ denotes the derivative of matrix $A$. This can be derived by premultiplying 
$$
A' v_p + A v_p' = \lambda_p' v_p + \lambda_p v_p'
$$

with $v_p^T$, imposing that the eigenvectors have unit length (and thus $v_p \cdot v_p' = 0$), and making use of the fact that $A$ is symmetric.

Say I want to use the same approach on the eigendecomposition of $A$
$$
A V = V \Lambda \\
A'V + A V' = V' \Lambda + V \Lambda' \\
V^T A'V + V^T A V' = V^T V' \Lambda + V^T V \Lambda' \\
V^T A'V + V^T A V' = V^T V' \Lambda + \Lambda' \\
\Lambda' = V^T A'V + V^T A V' - V^T V' \Lambda \\
\Lambda' = V^T A'V + \Lambda V^T V' - V^T V' \Lambda \\
$$

also

$$
I' = (V^T V)' = {V^T}'V + V^T V' = 0
$$

However, I don't see how I could use this statement to simplify the earlier expression. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

How can I express the derivative of the matrix of eigenvalues $\Lambda$ in terms of the derivative of $A$?

Comment: Is $A$ a function of $t$, or something like that? I ask because you differentiate, but you do not specify with respect to what. Also "eigenvalues have unit length" makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the typo. Yes, for example the entries of $A$ could be a function of $t$ and we are taking the derivative with respect to $t$.

Comment: It is much better to specify the dependence on $t$ in the main text. That's an important point.

Comment: Now I finally understood your question. It is a nice one, +1. I have a semi-serious question; I suppose that $$\Lambda'=\mathrm{diag}(V_1^TA'V_1, V_2^TA'V_2,\ldots, V_n^TA'V_n), $$ where $V_j$ denotes the $j$-th column of $V$, is not the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Oh, and wait a minute. If you impose that the eigenvectors are orthonormal, as you may since $A$ is symmetric, then $V$ is an orthogonal matrix, that is, $V^TV=I$. Differentiating this you should get something, just like in the beginning of the post you differentiated $v_i\cdot v_j=\delta_{ij}$. (HTH)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I hoped that there was a way to express $\Lambda'$ in a nice clean matrix notation, but from the result for the individual eigenvalues it follows that $\Lambda'$ is just a diagonal matrix with entry $(i,i)$ equal to $v_i^T A' v_i$ where $v_i$ is the $i$-th eigenvector.

Comment: If you include the Hadamard product $(\odot)$ in your "clean" matrix notation, then you can write $$d\Lambda' = I\odot(V^TA'V)$$